# RactiveJS: how can I test equality in a template expression?

Tags: javascript, binding, templating, ractivejs

I'm using a Ractive.JS binding:

```
var alertsBinding = new Ractive({
    el: '.alerts',
    template: alertsTemplate,
    data: {
        alerts: alerts,
        selectedAlertID: null
    }
});
```

The template uses a [template expression](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/expressions) to detect if an item is the currently selected item and add a class accordingly:

```
<div class="alert {{ id === selectedAlertID ? 'selected' }}">
  ...
</div>
```

When an item is selected, I run:

```
alertsBinding.set({selectedAlertID: selectedAlert.id});
```

After setting I can see the condition is always false, even when condition should be true. I have also checked by adding the following:

```
id{{ id}} selected{{ selectedAlertID}}
```

Inside the alert to confirms the item is actually selected.

[image]

Yet still the condition is false, and the class not set.

**How can I test equality in a template expression?**

Comment: as of just now, on the dev branch, this causes a parse error to be thrown: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/EM52x/

Answer (score 1):

The expression has to be legal JavaScript; in this case, there needs to be an alternative as well as a consequent:

```
<div class="alert {{ id === selectedAlertID ? 'selected' : '' }}">
  ...
</div>
```

When the parser doesn't see a colon followed by another expression, it stops trying to parse the ternary expression and falls back to treating it as a bog-standard reference. It would probably be helpful if the parser provided more feedback in these situations - I've [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/702).

As an alternative, you could also do

```
<div class="alert {{# id===selectedAlertID }}selected{{/}}">
  ...
</div>
```